# how to create Telerik UI mvc application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a new project using Telerik UI.

I downloaded trial version of Telerik DevCraft (with extensions to vs 2019) and newest version of visual studio 2019 (version 16.0.4) with WEB and ASP development packages, net core as well.

I'm able to create pure MVC project, but when im trying to create project Telerik ASP.NET MVC Application im gettin an error `this project template requires mvc 5 installed`.

I tried to create pure mvc project and convert it to Telerik Application but then error occurs `Visual Studio 2019 with installed Web development workload is required`

I'm a bit confused and i really don't know how to solve that.
I have installed all packages from `ASP.NET and web development` workload

Comment: Have you definitely pulled down the MVC package, and if so version 5? In Visual Studio go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console and type in the command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.7` in the window to get the latest MVC packages into your project

Comment: well, after error i have a blank VS page (without any solution/project).    
When im trying to do that on pure MVC project im getting info that the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7" package already exists in the "WebApplication2" project